# Dart - round down a double

Tags: flutter, dart

How can round this down in dart/flutter:

```
int hours = int.parse((minutes/60).toStringAsFixed(0));
```

**minutes/60** is **7.92**, and I want the result to be **7**
but it gets rounded up to 8...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use both the [Truncating division operator](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/num/operator_truncate_divide.html):

```
int hours = minutes ~/ 60;
```

Or the [floor method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/num/floor.html):

```
int hours = (minutes/60).floor();
```

Comment: Note this will round down for positive numbers, for negative numbers it will round up. If you know you need to handle negatives you can do `int hours = (minute/60).floor();`

Comment: Would be best to clarify that truncating division always rounds toward zero and that `floor()` always rounds toward negative infinity.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to round down with certain precision - use this:

```
double roundDown(double value, int precision) {
    final isNegative = value.isNegative;
    final mod = pow(10.0, precision);
    final roundDown = (((value.abs() * mod).floor()) / mod);
    return isNegative ? -roundDown : roundDown;
  }
```

roundDown(0.99, 1) => 0.9

roundDown(-0.19, 1) => -0.1